# Display page get many Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use spring boot 2 and thymeleaf 3.
On one of my page, when user click on a link

```
 <li th:class="${activeTab=='export'} ? 'active nav-item' : 'nav-item'">
     <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/menu/exports}" th:text="#{exports}"</a></li>
```

I get thoses errors

> jquery.inputpicker.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not
>   defined jquery.dataTables.min.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is
>   not defined dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   module is not defined dataTables.buttons.min.js:8 Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: module is not defined buttons.print.min.js:5 Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: module is not defined buttons.bootstrap4.min.js:5
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
>   dataTables.responsive.min.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not
>   defined responsive.bootstrap4.min.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: module
>   is not defined bootbox.min.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not
>   defined

In my script fragment

```
<div th:fragment="Scripts">

    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/jquery.inputpicker.js}"></script>
    ...
</div>
```

I paste my small page here
https://pastebin.com/qPbN5x9L

On my controller page

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/menu/exports"})
public String getExportsTemplate() {
    return "menu/exports";
}
```

changed id of the button, fixed the issue

Comment: Looks like your dependencies aren't getting loaded. Why do you think that is?

Comment: I'd take a look at using WebJars instead of linking to the JS that way

Comment: used webjar before... decided to return to js directly... that allowed to reduce build jar of 10mb